# Access derived class from base class shared function

Tags: vb.net

I would like to rewrite this function to avoid the need for a generic parameter because it should be available through some other means given the redundancy of how this function would be called (T should always refer to the class on which the function was called):

```
Public Shared Function FMXSize(Of T As {New, FileStructure})() As Integer
  Dim result As Integer
  If SizeCache.TryGetValue(GetType(T), result) Then Return result
  result = (New T()).CalculateSize()
  SizeCache(GetType(T)) = result
  Return result
End Function
```

It would be called like this with the current implementation (Note: `LibCtl` inherits from `FileStructure`):

```
Return LibCtl.FMXSize(Of LibCtl)()
```

Or like this with the ideal implementation (since the above looks redundant):

```
Return LibCtl.FMXSize()
```

Comment: Maybe this is better suited to codereview?

Comment: Technically this code is not under review yet, and this was just the easiest way to ask the question, "how do you access the derived class type from a base class shared function without explicitly providing it" with a realistic code sample. So I don't know if that makes a difference as to where this question belongs. The real reason I posted here, though, is that I haven't used codereview.stackexchange.com before, and I suspect it has far fewer people looking at it than stackoverflow does. I'm surprised that code review even warranted its own site.

Comment: you could override the base types `FMXSize` function on the child with the content of the childs function being `Return MyBase.FMXSize(Of LibCtl)()`. Not exactly what you want but Parent classes should never know or care who is inheriting them so attempting to would violate some OOP principles.

Comment: @Mike_OBrien Shared functions cannot be overridden, so that won't work.

Comment: In my opinion you are attempting to remove the generic nature of the base classes `FMXSize` function by allowing it to know what its actual type is, this requires that the Parent class know what could possibly be inheriting from it. As far as overriding is concerned, that actually makes sense, I didn't think about the shared aspect of the function, that was my mistake.

Comment: @Mike_OBrien Keeping information about the derived type in the base class did feel slightly icky to me too, but it has no reliance on that information (it's just an index into a cache so we don't have to recalculate the size of the derived type again), and I couldn't think of a way to avoid this in a shared function. The way I see it, as long as the code doesn't actually reference any derived classes, it hasn't broken that rule too badly. You can drop the same class into a completely different project and expect it to work without changes. (Is that "the test"?)

Comment: It looks to me as though you might be running into a notable absence from .NET, which is the ability to do dynamic dispatch with a `Shared` routine.